# Hall effect sensor on pump gives fluctuating state

Tags: arduino

I have a Hall effect sensor placed on the end of a liquid pump which circulates liquid through the in-floor heating. I want to get the state of the pump (on or off), then send that state to OpenHab via a serial port message. The trouble is that the state of the digital pin seems to fluctuate with either  the 60Hz current and/or the rotating pump impeller. Depending on the exact instance I am reading the pin, I might get a HIGH or LOW, even  though the pump is on. This sends spurious messages to OpenHab.

I know I can build a "latch" circuit using an OR gate with an AND gate, but I want to not have to add electronics (14 pumps in the heating system).

Is there a way to stabilize the sensor value?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a latching function for the pump Hall sensors. I am using a struct to hold the sensor and its settings, and a linked list for all the sensors:

```
struct s_PumpSensor
{
    /**
     * Name of the sensor
     */
    char *name;

    /**
     * The arduino pin number to read the information from
     */
    int pin;

    /**
     * The pump state
     */
    bool pumpOn;

    /**
     * How long to wait to ensure the pump is off
     */
    unsigned long offTimer;

    /**
     * The next one in line, or null
     */
    s_PumpSensor *next;
};
```

The latching code, called from a loop traversing the linked list:

```
void checkPumpSensor(s_PumpSensor *theSensor, unsigned long currentTime)
{
    bool pumpIsOn;
    bool isChange = false;

    pumpIsOn = (digitalRead(theSensor->pin) == LOW) ? true : false;

    if (theSensor->pumpOn == pumpIsOn)
        theSensor->offTimer = currentTime;

    else if (pumpIsOn)
        isChange = true;

    // Wait for 2 seconds before believing the sensor change to off
    if ((currentTime - theSensor->offTimer) > 2000)
        isChange = true;

    if (isChange)
    {
        theSensor->pumpOn = pumpIsOn;

        // send the state change to OpenHab
        Serial.print("Pump:");
        Serial.print(theSensor->name);
        Serial.print(":");
        Serial.println(theSensor->pumpOn ? "On" : "OFF");
    }
}
```

If the sensor has not changed, then the off timer is reset. The old state of the sensor is only updated if the pump was off and is now on, or the off time has expired.

The line `if ((currentTime - theSensor->offTimer) > 2000)` only triggers if the pump has been off for more than 2 seconds. Thus the pump magnetic field can fluctuate without triggering a change event.